# how to add value to array and separate by (vertical bar) not by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

so I wanted to get checked value to an array and add vertical bar instead of comma to separate each value, is there any way I could do so with Jquery map .get() function, any links or any suggestions ye can provide would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

```
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=groupABC]').change(function(){
    var checkedValues = $('input[name="groupABC"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get();

    alert(checkedValues);
   });
```

for above code logic i got [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]

what i want to get [a|b|c|d|e|f|g]

Comment: `checkedValues.replace(',','|');`?

Comment: Is expected result of `checkedValues` `Array` or `String` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what i want to get [a|b|c|d|e|f|g]

```
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=groupABC]').change(function(){
    var checkedValues = $('input[name="groupABC"]:checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('id');
    }).get().join("|");

    alert([checkedValues]);
   });
```

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
var res = [arr.join("|")];
document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: would you mind send me a link with more details on that (join), because i don't know what its call when i google it Thanks again :)

Comment: @Sameul.T See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 2):

When viewed in the console all array values will be separated by a comma (`,`) by default. The separator only matters when you convert the array to a string. If you want to change the separator used, you can pass it as a property to the `join()` function:

```
console.log(checkedValues.join('|')); // = a|b|c|d|e|f|g
```